# Grid in android studio

Tags: android, xml

Can someone please tell me how do I create an empty grid with black border on android studio ?

It should allow widgets inside the grid.

I've tried but the outcome is different to what I expected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We would love to help you. Can you please post the code you have tried so far so we can answer your question?

Comment: show what you tried, what is the output, and what you expected. This is the way you should ask a question here.

Comment: You should google for `android gridview`.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you can place any widget by using grid layout..Try this code...

//Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

//Sample.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class Sample extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Sample.this));
}
}
```

//ImageAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(170, 170));

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
 //here you can place the image
    R.drawable.ic_radio_2, R.drawable.ic_radio_3,
    R.drawable.ic_radio_4, R.drawable.ic_radio_5,
    R.drawable.ic_radio_4, R.drawable.ic_radio_6,

};
}
```