# How to show Image View using grid view in vertical position?

Tags: android, android-gridview

[image]

I am trying to make calendar. and I am use grid view with image .but image shows in the horizontal position. I want to show image in vertical position

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cAWs.png)
My design

Comment: show us your grid item model layout and the gird view itself

Comment: In your linear layout makes the orientation as vertical.So all the images in that linear layout will be in vertical.

Comment: Please avoid using titles like Sir in your questions, answers and comments -

Comment: ok.I update my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already posted these kind of gridview questions for your reference kindly go and refer and my layout is especially well suited for marketing app like structure and for your requirement it will match

**Try with this link:**
 [Grid in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013713/grid-in-android-studio/41033050#41033050)

Comment: @HasRaja  ...I will check ..Thank u

Comment: @PrashantPatil ok prashanth..if you like my answer vote for me..thanks in advance

Comment: @HasRaja Is it working like that?I am trying but no result

Comment: please any body help

Comment: for your reference :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: @HasRaja how to give vote?I am new on stack overflow.Thanks in advance

Comment: You have transparent check mark in right side of this question click it

Comment: @HasRaja I didnot get.